# Update Existing Excel Documents with new Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, content-type, excel, document

Is it possible to push changes to an Excel content type to all existing documents a document library with updated content type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the xlsx file that is associated with a content type and used as a template when a new Excel file is created from that content type, then

- any changes to the template file will have no effect whatsoever on workbooks already created with a previous version of the template.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**.
Changes made to a content type or its template will only apply to the document to be created, but not the existing documents.